# Making prolog queries from C++

Tags: c++, prolog

I am trying to be able to have a C++ application that, when certain events are triggered, makes a query to a prolog file and is returned the results from the query in C++. I believe prolog can do this, however I cannot find any adequate documentation on how to set up Prolog in C++ applications.

This also needs to work offline, meaning prolog queries do not depend on having another service or process running in order to run. Can this be done in C++? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried but should be possible.

Here is a [documentation page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/pl2cpp.html%27%29), with examples, for SWI Prolog and here is [another page](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~haemmerl/gprolog-rh/doc/manual072.html) for GProlog.